# Bootstrap pagination on ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, html

I have a table where I'm listing my restaurants

```
<table class="table">
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="row in restaurantList">
<td><img src="{{row.image}}"></td>
<td>{{row.name}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<table>
```

I'm getting all the names and photos correctly. But how can I paginate the collected data, 10 by 10 in bootstrap without plugins ?

Comment: check this demo https://codepen.io/khilnani/pen/qEWojX

Answer (score 0):

If you are using both angularjs and bootstrap, it would be interesting for you to also use the [bootstrap-ui library](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

It is really easy to use and it provides a lot of UI components (one of them is a pagination directive).

I don't know if it is what you mean when you say "without plugins" ? That's just one js file to load in your site, and you already have all the required dependencies.

I hope it helps